# Displaying only specific records matching a condition from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database

```
   Device  |   Status
  --------------------  
     TV1   |    off
     TV2   |    on
     PC    |    on
    Printer|    off
    ...    |   ...
```

I need to generate an html table, using php, displaying ONLY the devices with status ON.
The table rows must show the device name and a blinking_led.gif looking like this:

```
 Device  |  Status
 -----------------
 TV2     |  'blinking_led.gif'
 PC      |  'blinking_led.gif'
```

Comment: Sorry, but if you cannot write this simple query and/or a simple HTML page with a table on it yourself **then you need to hit a book or some beginners tutorials**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you know how to handle with `PDO`, change "tablename" with yours table name in database, and data in connection.

```
<?php

// create PDO mysql connection
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=host_name;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Device, Status FROM tablename WHERE Status = 'on'");
$stmt->execute();

// get all data where status is on
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo '<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Device</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>';

foreach ($data as $key)
{
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$key['Device'].'</td>
            <td><img src="blinking_led.gif"></td>
        </tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Edited due to typo in code, forgot to close brackets in `foreach` loop

Comment: Perfect! It works perfectly, thanks

Comment: No problem, anytime.